# running ssh from a subroutine in powershell on Windows fails

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh

running ssh from command Line on Powershell 7 (x64) works fine;

ssh user@host "linux_command parameters" yields the expected output. (using public/private key pair)

but not from my subroutine 'Create' in powershell that's event driven.

`(Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier Create -Action $Create)`

The create function is fine, I tested it with simply outputting text to a terminal, only the ssh call in it fails.

I found an issue on stackoverflow 12 years ago that mentions a similar problem (ssh fails when is being called within windows service).

The solution then was to call ssh with the -n option. Actually this does work, but I do not understand why.
The -N option is  "Do not execute a remote command."
and I cannot find an -n option for ssh.

Can someone enlighten me on this subject, I would like to understand why this works and whether it is the optimal solution?

Comment: What account are you using to start the service?  A service by default starts with a System Account with No Environment so the path of the ssh is not found.  It is best to create a Service Account (like a user account with admin permission) that has an environment.  The start the service using the Service Account.

Comment: I am using Powershell 7 within a user account which has admin rights.

Comment: Try starting powershell by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Sorry, but this has no relevance with respect to my question about the -n option.

Comment: It is in the linux manual page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html

Comment: thanks @jdweng, so it doesn't wait for input from stdin to continue.

Comment: It is the commands after you login.  It is used when you want to take the command for the remote machine from a file instead of from the keyboard.  As it say in the manual it must be used when running in background and doesn't work when you need to enter a username and password.